Column Width in Tables
This is my first time making a table and I would like to have a table with uneven columns, maybe 25% and 75%. I have been playing around with hsize but still getting my head around it. What is causing that white block in the header row - almost like a margin or third column? Thanks
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,table]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{008ED7}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.75}
\definecolor{lightBlue}{HTML}{e5f7ff}


\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{s X}

\arrayrulecolor{blue}\hline
\rowcolor{lightBlue} \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Name}} & \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Details}} \\
\hline

\vspace{0.1cm}
\small\textbf {Document Name} & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
\vspace{0.1cm}
\small{
Here is a paragraph of text
\begin{itemize}[label=$\circ$]
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
 \item Item 3
 \item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.1cm}
}
\end{minipage}\\
\arrayrulecolor{mygray}\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{center}


\end{document}



What is causing that white block in the header row ?

Indeed your new column type "s". If you want a first column of about the 25%, try with  p{0.25\linewidth}, but note that the left-right column padding (\tabcolsep) also matter for the total width, i.e., a normal tabular with p{.25\linewidth}p{.75\linewidth} columns will be more that 100% of the line
Moreover, if the table is \textwidth, there is no need to center it, just avoid the indentation if there are any. Note that in this case \linewidth and \textwidth are the same length, but \linewidth could be smaller if there are indentation, inside list, table, minipages, etc..
On the other hand, I have taken the liberty of remove the minipage, the \vspaces, the table [t]op alignment, and change the rules with the help of booktabs package:

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,table]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{008ED7}
\definecolor{lightBlue}{HTML}{e5f7ff}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.25\linewidth}X}
\specialrule{1pt}{10pt}{0pt}
\rowcolor{lightBlue}
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Name}} &
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Details}}\\
\specialrule{.4pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\small\bfseries Document Name &
\small Here is a paragraph of text 
\begin{itemize}[label=$\circ$]
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
 \item Item 3
 \item Item 4
\end{itemize} \\\specialrule{1pt}{2pt}{10pt}
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{document}


Thank you. Your response really helped my understanding, I appreciate it.
